# use slash as parameter for action method in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have one MVC application where I have one action method in home controller, Below is the details:

```cs
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
  //some value

    return View();
}
```

Now when I run application so in URL I put "localhost:1469/Home/Index/10"

so that 10 value should appear in id parameter of action method.

Below is my route code is used:

```sc
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "About", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

How would I achieve the same?

Comment: Can anyone look for this issue?

Comment: What is the issue? You have not given a problem statement.